# В чем смысл uvicorn? django python

Tags: python, django, асинхронность, uvicorn

У меня есть следующий view:

```
async def index(request: HttpRequest):
    await sleep(10)
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

Читая документацию django и различные гайды, я запустил свой проект через uvicorn, что бы как я на тот момент думал "в моем проекте асинхронность начала работать как задумывалась"

Но когда я вызвал этот view я не заметил никакой разницы между работой через uvicorn и работы через manage.py runserver.

Так в чем же смысл uvicorn и как его правильно понять?

Так в чем

Comment: А теперь попробуйте вызвать этот view десять раз одновременно

Comment: «асинхронность начала работать как задумывалась» — а как она вами задумывалась-то? Что вы ожидали получить?

Comment: @andreymal, Я запустил этот view с двух устройств одновременно (с ноутбука и компьютера). Ожидал что сначала view закончит работу на одном из устройств, после чего начнёт на другом, но в итоге они пришли одновременно. (Запускал через runserver)

Comment: В каком смысле задумывалась? Если я правильно понял вопрос, то я понимаю нормальную работу корутин в одном лупе и конкурентно, а не последовательно

Comment: Если я правильно помню, с относительно недавних пор `runserver` по умолчанию работает в многопоточном режиме, что и объясняет одновременность

Comment: Не нашел этого в документации django 4.1

Comment: [Всё там есть](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver): «The server is multithreaded by default»

Comment: А ещё меня в принципе смущает ваш интерес к runserver, так что на всякий случай также обратите внимание на фразу «DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING»

Comment: Да, сейчас видел в документации пункт об этом

Comment: Все, понял, разобрался, огромное спасибо. Напишете ответ к этому вопросу, или ответить самому?

Comment: Ну вообще по логике у вас должен возникнуть вопрос «ну и зачем нужна асинхронность, если есть многопоточность») Впрочем, на эту тему вроде много информации в интернете есть

Comment: Когда я задавал этот вопрос я был не знал что runserver использует многопоточность по дефолту, поэтому скорее всего заголовок у вопроса правильный, а вот тело составлено не правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) — это веб-сервер поддерживающий протокол [ASGI](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) для Python.

Следущая команда:

> manage.py runserver

Запускает сервер для разработки. Не предназначенный для использования в проде.